# Show implicit assignment of unexported field 'data' in simplejson.Json literal when use bitly's go-simplejson

Tags: json, go

When I use like `&simplejson.Json{v}` (v is a interface read from file and it's actual data structure is map[string]interface{}), then show this error. Details:

A json file named **abcd**

```
{
    "pids": [
        { 
            "pid": 168043, 
            "target_regions": [
                40, 
                25, 
                43, 
                299, 
                240
            ]
         },
        { 
            "pid": 168044, 
            "target_regions": [
                63, 
                65,
                68
            ]
        }
    ]
```

}

And the go file is

```
package main    

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"    

    sjson "github.com/bitly/go-simplejson"
)    

type pidInfo struct {
    Pid           uint64   `json:"pid"`
    TargetRegions []uint32 `json:"target_regions"`
}    

type pidUnitInfo struct {
    Pid2Info map[uint64]*pidInfo
}    

func build() error {
    content, _ := ioutil.ReadFile("./abcd")
    json, err := sjson.NewJson(content)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    newPidUnitInfo(json)
    return nil
}    

func newPidUnitInfo(json *sjson.Json) (*pidUnitInfo, error) {
    newInfo := new(pidUnitInfo)
    newInfo.buildPid2Info(json)
    return nil, nil
}    

func (pui *pidUnitInfo) buildPid2Info(json *sjson.Json) error {
    raw, ok := json.CheckGet("pids")
    if !ok {
        return fmt.Errorf("not found json key %v", "pids")
    }
    pids, err := raw.Array()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    pui.Pid2Info = make(map[uint64]*pidInfo, len(pids))
    for _, v := range pids {
        fmt.Println(v)
        m := &sjson.Json{v}
        fmt.Println(m)
    }
    return nil
}    

func main() {
    build()
}
```

When I execute it, show `implicit assignment of unexported field 'data' in simplejson.Json literal` at this line `m := &sjson.Json{v}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
m := &sjson.Json{v}
```

Tries to create a value (and take the address) of the struct type `Json` from package `go-simplejson`. The type declaration is:

```
type Json struct {
    data interface{}
}
```

It has one field: `data` which is unexported. That means packages other than `go-simplejson` cannot refer to this field. When you use a struct literal `&sjson.Json{v}`, it would try to initialize the `Json.data` field with value `v` which is a violation of this. You cannot do this.

The `Json` type is not designed for you to specify the internal `data`, it is designed so that the `data` will be the placeholder of some decoded JSON data (see the [`NewFromReader()`](https://godoc.org/github.com/bitly/go-simplejson#NewFromReader) and [`NewJson()`](https://godoc.org/github.com/bitly/go-simplejson#NewJson) constructor-like functions).

This `data` field is handled internally by the `go-simplejson` package, you cannot set it yourself. You may use [`sjson.New()`](https://godoc.org/github.com/bitly/go-simplejson#New) to obtain a new `*Json` value which will initialize this `data` field with an empty map (`map[string]interface{}`). You may also use [`Json.Map()`](https://godoc.org/github.com/bitly/go-simplejson#Json.Map) method which asserts that `data` is a map and returns it like that:

```
js := sjson.New()
m, err := js.Map()
if err != nil {
    // Handle error
}

// Now you have a map of type map[string]interface{}
```

Or to populate the `data` inside a `Json`, you can use its [`Json.Set()`](https://godoc.org/github.com/bitly/go-simplejson#Json.Set) method.